# jquery mobile change checkbox color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

How can i change the checkbox color(blue) and checkbox icon color(white) when checked to other colors.

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <form>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0 ">Check me
        </label>
    </form>
```

Comment: While changing the background color is trivial CSS, for the icon color you have two color sets: *white* and *black*. You can display *black* icons by appliyng the class `ui-alt-icon`. You can't colorize icons because icons images aren't inlined. Here is the reference for the alternate icon set: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/icons/

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is identify the class which is used by jquery. After that you can simply apply the property like this

```css
.ui-btn.ui-checkbox-on:after {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.ui-btn.ui-checkbox-off:after {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0 ">Check me
        </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For blue color:

```
.ui-btn.ui-checkbox-on.ui-btn-a:after {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

The white icon is a SVG:

```
.ui-icon-check:after {
    background-image: url(newicon.svg);
}
```